# I would look so cool in that hat

Tags: pattern, knowledge, visual, seasonal

What **common theme** do the missing elements have?

Group 1

> [image]

Group 2

> [image]

Group 3

> [image]

Group 4

> [image]

---

<sub>Image credits:

1.3 Hex, CC-BY-SA 3.0

2.1 Nevit Dilmen, CC-BY-SA 3.0

2.2 Cramyourspam, CC-BY-SA 4.0

3.2 Jens Buurgaard Nielsen, CC-BY-SA 3.0

4.2 Saffron Blaze, CC-BY-SA 3.0

Others PD/CC0</sub>

Comment: You never cease to amaze, Jafe ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The **common theme** is

> **bird**

Group 1

> China, Jordan, [Panama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama_hat), **Turkey** (Country that have a star on its flag?)

Group 2

> Firefly, Poison Ivy, Joker, **Penguin** (Batman villain)

Group 3

> orange, squash, date, **Kiwi** (fruit)

Group 4

> queen, knight, [king](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willem-Alexander_of_the_Netherlands), **Rook** (chess piece)

---

The title said “I would look so cool in that hat”

> Your current winter bash 2018 hat has a **bird** on it.
>  [image]

Comment: Nice work! Everything's correct.